# Can I see if a timer is still running?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Simple question here that I can't seem to find an answer for: Once a `setTimeout` is set, is there any way to see if it's still, well, set?

```
if (!Timer)
{
    Timer = setTimeout(DoThis,60000);
}
```

From what I can tell, when you `clearTimeout`, the variable remains at its last value. A `console.log` I just looked at shows `Timer` as being '12', no matter if the timeout has been set or cleared. Do I have to null out the variable as well, or use some other variable as a boolean saying, yes, I have set this timer? Surely there's a way to just check to see if the timeout is still running... right? I don't need to know how long is left, just if it's still running.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There isn't anyway to interact with the timer except to start it or stop it.  I typically null the timer variable in the timeout handler rather than use a flag to indicate that the timer isn't running.  There's a nice description on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) about how the timer works. In their example they use a flag variable.

The value you are seeing is a [*handle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)) to the current timer, which is used when you clear (stop) it.

Comment: -1 patrick, that's not a worldly principle. sometimes they've got useful resources.

Comment: OT: the problem is distinguishing those times from the others :) Without knowing about the topic, of course

Comment: "I typically null the timer variable in the timeout "

Comment: Perhaps you meant "I typically null the timer variable before starting a timer"?

Answer (score 78):

What I do is:

```
var timer = null;

if (timer != null) {
  window.clearTimeout(timer); 
  timer = null;
}
else {
  timer = window.setTimeout(yourFunction, 0);
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(yourFunction, 0)`, safer than `setTimeout('yourFunction()', 0)`.

Comment: @Epirocks Even in the asynchronous world, Javascript is still single threaded.

Comment: I was just making the point that it would be nice if there was a way to ask the timer is it still running. I had a page full of asynchronous requests at the time and was finding this solution above a bit over simplified but cannot remember enough to go into details, wish I had.

Comment: why do you clear _and_ null? does `clearTimeout` not ensure it's not being taking up memory? Cheers. (Sorry I know this is from ages ago)

Comment: @1252748, the variable `timer` still keeps its value (a timer ID), even when `window.clearTimeout` is called. So it's necessary to reset it.

Answer (score 29):

There is no need to check for an existing timer, just execute `clearTimeout` before starting the timer.

```
var timer;
//..
var startTimer = function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(DoThis, 6000);
}
```

This will clear any timer before starting a new instance.

Comment: Working fine, exactly as I looked for. Thanks.This answer deserves more upvotes.

Comment: There is a **need** to check. Just because you haven't thought of a need doesn't mean there is none :)

Comment: In my case, I have a `setTimeout` function that needs to be running at all times. The check is to make sure if the server crashes and restarts, the users who rely on the `setTimeout` function immediately regain the functionality after restart. `clearTimeout` does not help my reason to ask this question.

Answer (score 5):

Set another variable `Timer_Started = true` with your timer. And also change the variable to `false` when the timer function is called:

```
// set 'Timer_Started' when you setTimeout
var Timer_Started = true;
var Timer = setTimeout(DoThis,60000);

function DoThis(){

   // function DoThis actions 
   //note that timer is done.
   Timer_Started = false;

}

function Check_If_My_Timer_Is_Done(){

   if(Timer_Started){
      alert("The timer must still be running.");
   }else{
      alert("The timer is DONE.");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

*I know this is a necroposting but i think still people are looking for this.*

This is what i use:
3 variables:

1. `t` for milliseconds since.. in Date Object for next target
2. `timerSys` for the actual interval
3. `seconds` threshold for milliseconds has been set

next i have a `function timer` with 1 variable the function checks if variable is *truly*, if so he check if timer is already running and if this is the case than fills the *global vars*  , if not *truly*, *falsely*, clears the interval  and set `global var timerSys` to **false**;

```
var t, timerSys, seconds;

function timer(s) {
  if (s && typeof s === "number") {
    if (typeof timerSys === "boolean" || typeof timerSys === "undefined") {
      timerSys = setInterval(function() {
        sys();
      }, s);
      t = new Date().setMilliseconds(s);
      seconds = s;
    }
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerSys);
    timerSys = false;
  }
  return ((!timerSys) ? "0" : t)
}

function sys() {
  t = new Date().setMilliseconds(seconds);

}
```

**Example I**

Now you can add a line to *sys function*:

```
function sys() {
  t = new Date().setMilliseconds(seconds);
  console.log("Next execution: " + new Date(t));
//this is also the place where you put functions & code needed to happen when interval is triggerd

}
```

And execute :

```
  timer(5000);
```

Every 5 seconds in console:

```
  //output:: Next execution: Sun May 08 2016 11:01:05 GMT+0200 (Romance (zomertijd))
```

**Example II**

```
function sys() {
  t = new Date().setMilliseconds(seconds);
  console.log("Next execution: " + seconds/1000 + " seconds");

}

$(function() {
  timer(5000);
});
```

Every 5 seconds in console:

```
      //output:: Next execution: 5 seconds
```

**Example III**

```js
var t, timerSys, seconds;

function timer(s) {
  if (s && typeof s === "number") {
    if (typeof timerSys === "boolean" || typeof timerSys === "undefined") {
      timerSys = setInterval(function() {
        sys();
      }, s);
      t = new Date().setMilliseconds(s);
      seconds = s;
    }
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerSys);
    timerSys = false;
  }
  return ((!timerSys) ? "0" : t)
}

function sys() {
  t = new Date().setMilliseconds(seconds);
  console.log("Next execution: " + seconds / 1000 + " seconds");

}

$(function() {
  timer(5000);

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("span").text(t - new Date());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Freebeer</button>
<span></span>
```

***Note this way you can go below 0***

Answer (score 3):

I usually nullify the timer:

```
var alarm = setTimeout(wakeUpOneHourLater, 3600000);
function wakeUpOneHourLater() {
    alarm = null;    //stop alarm after sleeping for exactly one hour
}
//...
if (!alarm) {
    console.log('Oops, waked up too early...Zzz...');
}
else {
    console.log('Slept for at least one hour!');
}
```