# program stuck at clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I realize that it is very troublesome when i have a selector to clear the timer but if the timer is not set, the program will stuck at `clearInterval()`. Take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tw4A7/

Button one is to `setInterval()` and button two is to `clearInterval()`. If i click on button two first, it will stuck, and will not continue the rest of the function. This is just an example of some scenarios whereby i may have a condition or selector to set the timer and when another condition is met, it has to get out from the timer loop.

But of course, it can be solved if i put `clearInterval()` at the last part of the function. However sometimes the timer has to be stopped before doing anything else.

Is there a way to check if the timer has start? only then it will get clear? Or else, it will skip the `clearInterval()` and proceed?

As request, hjpotter:

```
$('#1').click(function(){
    $('#test').append("0");
loop=setInterval(function(){
    $('#test').append("1");

}, 1000);
});

$('#2').click(function(){
   window.clearInterval(loop);
   $('#test').html("2");
});
```

Comment: Please include the code from fiddle to the question too

Comment: `if (loop) window.clearInterval(loop);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I see if a timer is still running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247173/can-i-see-if-a-timer-is-still-running)

Comment: @elclanrs it will fail, you need to test `if(typeof loop != 'undefined')`

Comment: @Boaz i don't find solution there. but thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because loop is undefined.

If you look at the browser console you can see that there is an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: loop is not defined`. It is because you are trying to refer a variable called `loop` which is not yet defined.

When you press the `Button1` first you defines the variable and initiate it with the interval value that is why the error is not throwing.

Since you are using `loop` as a shared global variable the solution is to define the variable using `var` statement in a scope shared between both the methods.

```
var loop;
$('#1').click(function(){
    $('#test').append("0");
    loop=setInterval(function(){
        $('#test').append("1");

    }, 1000);
});
$('#2').click(function(){
    window.clearInterval(loop);
    $('#test').html("2");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7GsKW/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny there are none

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to define a array to save the timer which created when you click the button,if don't so and click the button 1 multiple times,even the timer is defined,each time a new timer will replace it,so you can't stop the previous timer.

```
var loopList;
$('#1').click(function(){
    $('#test').append("0");
    var loop=setInterval(function(){
        $('#test').append("1");

    }, 1000);
    loopList.push(loop);
});
$('#2').click(function(){
    $.each(loopList,function(i,n){
        window.clearInterval(n);
    });
    $('#test').html("2");
});
```