# JS: check if setTimeout has finished or been canceled

Tags: javascript

I am creating a script that will execute a task after a certain amount of time has passed. I want the user to be able to cancel execution of these tasks. I can do this by saving the timeout to a list which I then use to cancel all timeouts. However if the timeout completes normally it is still stored in that list.

How do I check if a timeout has already been completed or canceled before attempting to clear it?

```
var timeouts = [];

$(document).on('click', '.doTask', function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        doTaskAfter();
    }, 10000);
    timeouts.push(timeout);
});

$(document).on('click', '.cancelTasks', function() {
    var i = timeouts.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (timeouts[i].finished || timeouts[i].timeoutCleared) { // How to I check this?
            clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
        }
        timeouts.splice(i, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you'd need to track the completion of a timeout yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I see if a timer is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247173/can-i-see-if-a-timer-is-still-running)

Comment: What you can do is you remove the timer ID from the `timeouts` array once it has completed. Then when you iterate through `timeouts` later you know that you will not encounter a completed timer.

Comment: I might not fully understand the question but why do you care if a timeout is finished or not? It seems like you want to cancel all timers, why not just have `clearTimeout(timeouts[i])` in your `while`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using promises.

Every time that you create a timer, put it inside of a promise, and push that promise into the array. The promise will resolve once the timer has ran.

Literally write your timer like..

```
   setTimeout(() => {
       resolve("True");
    }, 10000);
```

From there, what you can do is this. When you walk through your code, use promise.race, along with a second promise that returns false.

```
let race = [timeouts[i],Promise.resolve("False") ]
```

Use Promise.race to find if the promise has resolved. This works because if they have both resolved, Promise.race will return the first Promise, which will return "True". If your timer is still out, then it will return false.

```
Promise.race(race).then((res, rej) => {
if(res === true) {
clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but why would you remove already finished timeouts?

The timeout can remove itself from the array once it completes:

```
timeouts.splice(timeouts.indexOf(timeout), 1);
```

Otherwise you can use `clearTimeout` and `splice` to kill all registered/running timeouts from your timeouts list.

```
var timeouts = [];

$(document).on('click', '.doTask', function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        doTaskAfter();
        timeouts.splice(timeouts.indexOf(timeout), 1); // <=== HERE
    }, 10000);
    timeouts.push(timeout);
});

$(document).on('click', '.cancelTasks', function() {
    var i = timeouts.length;
    while (i--) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
        timeouts.splice(i, 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may or may not matter is that calling `clearTimeout` on an already cleared or completed timeout [doesn't do anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout#Notes), so you might not need to keep track of it.

Otherwise, you can just keep track of the state, something like:

```
var timeouts = [];

$(document).on('click', '.doTask', function() {
    var timeout = { state: 'waiting' };
    timeout.id = setTimeout(() => {
        timeout.state = 'finished';
        doTaskAfter();
    }, 10000);
    timeouts.push(timeout);
});

$(document).on('click', '.cancelTasks', function() {
    var i = timeouts.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (timeouts[i].state !== 'finished' && timeouts[i].state !== 'canceled') {
            // i.e. timeouts[i].state is 'waiting'
            clearTimeout(timeouts[i].id);
            timeouts[i].state = 'canceled';
        }
        timeouts.splice(i, 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put the function that contains the code you need to execute inside the set timeout like this:

```
setTimeout(() => { youfunction()}, 2000)

yourfunction(){

put your code here
}
```

`yourfunction` will execute after 2 second.