# Javascript: Start setTimeout() only if it hasn't been set already

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a vibrate function that I want to execute every 3 seconds or so until a button is clicked
My way of trying to do this is by having a loop that executes until a condition is false, when the button is clicked, the condition gets set to false. I could use sleep inside my while loop, followed by a call to vibrate, except that I would like to break as soon as the button is clicked, and not have to wait 3 seconds or so.

I am trying to set a timeOut if the device is still vibrating, but I don't want to continually set timeouts, I only want one timeout set at a time, so that a timeout is only set if one is not set already

```
this.vibrate()
while(this.state.isVibrating){
  if (timeout has not been set){
      setTimeout(this.vibrate(), 3000)
  }                
}
clearTimeout()
```

Comment: Perhaps this might help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247173/can-i-see-if-a-timer-is-still-running

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`.

Comment: [setInterval, clearinterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval) seems a better choice here

Comment: @Yousername I want to prevent the rest of the function from executing until  the condition is true though. There's some code after clearTimeout() that I do not want to execute until the vibration stops

Comment: The argument to `setTimeout` needs to be a function reference, not a function call.

Comment: `setTimeout(this.vibrate.bind(this), 3000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `setInterval` is a better option here.

```js
let interval;

this.vibrate();

interval = setInterval(this.vibrate.bind(this), 3000);
```

Then you can have a function execute when the button is clicked that can clear the interval:

```js
function buttonClicked() {
   clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Just make sure the `interval` var is in the scope of the buttonClicked function.

Comment: I want to prevent the rest of the function from executing until the condition is true though. There's some code after clearTimeout() that I do not want to execute until the vibration stops

Comment: @Sam You can't do that. JavaScript is single-threaded, so a condition can't change while a function is running.

Comment: @Sam It sounds like you need to restructure your code a bit then. It's not good practice prevent some code from running with a `while` loop